# Why am I unable to set DatePicker font size?

Tags: javafx, datepicker

I developed an javafx application for touch screens. Because of that I set all text fields with a 45px font size:

```
.text-field{
    -fx-font: 45px "Arial";
}
```

Now I want to use a normal sized DatePicker but I seem unable to change the font size:

```
<DatePicker fx:id="dpInitialDate" styleClass="my-date-picker"/>
```

css file:

```
.date-picker {
    -fx-font: 15px "Arial";
}

.date-picker.text-field {
    -fx-font: 15px "Arial";
}

.my-date-picker {
    -fx-font: 15px "Arial";
}

.my-date-picker.text-field {
    -fx-font: 15px "Arial";
}
```

It still presents an 45px font. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a space between `.my-date-picker` and `.text-field`. You want to select `TextField`s that are child nodes of the `DatePicker` control, not nodes that have both a `date-picker` style class *and* and `text-field` style class.